# Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

as a preface - my only experience with Ubuntu is playing around on VM's, so I apologize in advance for any naivety.

I've just updated my Yoga 2 Pro from Windows 8.1 to 10, and am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 along side. I created a UEFI bootable USB with Ubuntu 14.04.2 using rufus [as described](http://iseborn.eu/2014/08/14/installing-windows-8-1-and-ubuntu-14-04-on-the-lenovo-yoga-2/).

I disabled secure boot and fast boot and enabled USB boot in the BIOS menu. I was able to get 'try Ubuntu' running, but when I go to install, I get errors with the grub install.

When I select `/dev/sda` as the pointer for the boot loader, I get the error:

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
```

This is followed by the installation crashing.

Looking online, it seems like others had this issue, but it was resolved when they pointed the boot loader to `/dev/sda2` (which is where the Windows Boot Manager is). Unfortunately, I get another error when I do this:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda2' failed. This is a fatal error.
```

If it matters, I elected to not have separate root and home partitions due to a smaller SSD. So I have a partition, sda8, that is a 8gb swap partition and a ~25gb root partition, sda9, formated in Ext4 and mounted at `/`.

EDIT: I've tried going through [the suggested steps](/q/221835) to no avail. I tried to install 15.04 as well (the above link seems to indicate that alone could resolve some UEFI related issues) but got the same errors. Ubuntu seems to be installing (the installer sees a previous install in the correct partition), but crashes at the boot loader.

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION: I'm not sure what solved it, but here is what I did in case anyone else has the same issue. Some how the EFI partition corrupted. I deleted the ubuntu partitions using a live USB, then deleted /EFI/boot/Ubuntu. This lead to a failure to boot windows as well, so I used a windows recovery USB to repair windows boot manager. Then, in windows, I created the partitions for a clean ubuntu install. Finally, I reinstalled with no problem.

Comment: Is there any other error on why it is not installing grub? I might try Boot-Repair and see it it installs. Did you boot in UEFI mode not BIOS mode?  Shows first screens in either mode: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Run Boot Info report first: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Oldfred, I tried Boot-Repair. It failed, but I think might have given a key piece of info: An error occurred during the repair.

A new file (~/Boot-Info_2015-08-02__16h33.txt) will open in your text viewer.


In case you still experience boot problem, indicate its content to:
boot.repair@gmail.com 

Locked-ESP detected.... It looks like this can becaused by a corrupt  grubx64.efi. So now I just need to figure out how to fix that

Comment: You can post error logs to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and then post the URLs to your documents here so that we can look them over. IIRC, the Ubuntu installer does not prompt for a location for GRUB when installing in EFI mode, so my guess is you were actually installing in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

Comment: Rod, when I was installing I choose 'something else' in the install menu which gave me the option to manual specify the GRUB location - however, it is totally with in the realm of possibility that I am mistaken and am in legacy mode (although my BIOS is set in UEFI mode).  I made some progress in that I was able to get the locked ESP file resolved. I reattempted to install and it seemed to work, however instead of getting the usual GRUB menu, I get a terminal that says "Minimal BASH-line line editing is supported... grub>".  The boot-repair URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/11990025/

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.